# about file upload on PHP

Tags: php

I have question about the file upload.

this is **HTML** source.

```
<th scope="row">upload file</th> 
<td> 
    <input id="file" name="file" type="file" title="lable text"> 
</td>
```

here is file properties.

```
path : /www/temp/bulk_files
```

Type: **Folder**

```
Location : ftp://anisfra@example.com//www/anisfra/www/partner/bulk_files
```

What am I use that?

also I was using set permissions like here.

```
@chmod('ftp://anisfra@example.com/www/anisfra/www/partner/bulk_files', 0777);
```

but, it doesn't work.

what am I missing?

Comment: Is your question how to upload a file to an FTP server...?

Comment: Even though they ryme, you should use a `label` instead of a `table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="file">Filename:</label>
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

after that  get the  file attribute

```
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br />";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
```

then  pass the  atribute to upload function like

```
move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]
);
echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Comment: here is result.
Upload: 35513.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 72.76953125 kB
Temp file: /tmp/phptTfUN0
Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/35513.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/plus1000/www/partner/bulk_update.php on line 60 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phptTfUN0' to 'upload/35513.jpg' in /www/plus1000/www/partner/bulk_update.php on line 60 Stored in: upload/35513.jpg

Comment: echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];    here  you need  to create the upload folder and and provide the exact path where you want to store image  upload is you folder name

Comment: So you mean is this path?
ftp://anisfra@example.com//www/anisfra/www/partner/bulk_files

Comment: yes  you need to pass the exact path of upload directory for testing you can pass the static path